# Android update view of the fragment activity which is not in foreground

Tags: android

I am having a `FragmentActivity` whose view is updated by a Adapter with the help of bindview. The textview `strText` in the adapter needs to be updated. The code for the Adapter is like -

```
public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
 @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        viewHolder.time.setText(strText); 
}
}
```

The problem is there is an automatic pop-up launched by the `FragmentActivity` and when the pop-up is launched, I need to update the textview in the adapter. But the FragmentActivity is in background and the `notifyDataSetChanged()` although is called in Adapter, the view is not being updated. How can I achieve this

Comment: save the strText using a database or shared preferences, and when your activity is resumed or created fetch data from it.

Comment: How are you getting your `Cursor` for CursorAdapter?